# $L^{1}$-norm of smooth function with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

By the Hahn-Banach theorem, if $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ then

$\|f\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}=\sup\limits_{\|g\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\leq 1}\int fg$

If I replace $g \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for $\bar{g} \in \ C^{\infty}_{0} (\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for $\bar{f} \in C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$  , the equality above holds? I.e

$||\bar{f}||_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}=\sup\limits_{||\bar{g}||_{\infty}\leq 1}\int \bar{f}\bar{g}$

Where $||\bar{g}||_{\infty}=\sup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}|\bar{g}(x)|$

If true, how to prove it?

Comment: You can maybe choose $\overline{g}$ to be $\mathrm{sgn}\, f$ in open neighborhoods where $f\neq 0$ and then make it smooth. Enlarging these neighborhoods will send $\int \overline{f}\overline{g}$ to $\int |\overline{f}|$.

Answer (score 0):

Fix an positive integer $N$ and $\epsilon>0$.  Let $S=\overline{\{x\in\overline{B}_{N}(0): f(x)\ne 0\}}$ and $g(x)=\text{sgn}f(x)$, $x\in S$ and zero elsewhere. Now find a smooth supported mollifier $\{\varphi_{\delta}\}$. Then $\varphi_{\delta}\ast g$ is supported in $B_{N+\epsilon}(0)$ for all sufficiently small $\delta>0$. We have

\begin{align*}
\int_{B_{N+\epsilon}(0)}|f|&=\int_{N<|x|<N+\epsilon}|f|+\int_{\overline{B}_{N}(0)}|f|\\
&\leq\|f\|_{L^{1}(U_{N,\epsilon})}+\int_{\overline{B}_{N}(0)}(fg-f\varphi_{\delta}\ast g)+\int_{\overline{B}_{N}(0)}f\varphi_{\delta}\ast g\\
&\leq\|f\|_{L^{1}(U_{N,\epsilon})}+\|f\|_{L^{1}}\|g-\varphi_{\delta}\ast g\|_{L^{\infty}(\overline{B}_{N}(0))}+\int_{{\bf{R}}^{n}}f\varphi_{\delta}\ast g-\int_{N<|x|<N+\epsilon}f\varphi_{\delta}\ast g\\
&\leq\|f\|_{L^{1}(U_{N,\epsilon})}+\|f\|_{L^{1}}\|g-\varphi_{\delta}\ast g\|_{L^{\infty}(\overline{B}_{N}(0))}+M+\|f\|_{L^{1}(U_{N,\epsilon})}\|\varphi_{\delta}\ast g\|_{L^{\infty}(U_{N,\epsilon})},
\end{align*}
where $U_{N,\epsilon}=\{N<|x|<N+\epsilon\}$, and $M$ is the supremum in question. Note that $\|\varphi_{\delta}\ast g\|_{L^{\infty}(U_{N,\epsilon})}\leq\|\varphi_{\delta}\|_{L^{1}(U_{N,\epsilon})}\|g\|_{L^{\infty}(U_{N,\epsilon})}\leq 1$, so taking $\delta\rightarrow 0$, then $\displaystyle\int_{B_{N+\epsilon}(0)}|f|\leq 2\|f\|_{L^{1}(U_{N,\epsilon})}+M$. Now taking $\epsilon\downarrow 0$ we get $\displaystyle\int_{B_{N}(0)}|f|\leq M$. The rest just taking $N\rightarrow\infty$, we have $\|f\|_{L^{1}({\bf{R}}^{n})}\leq M$.